# How do I find Haplogroup X from AncestryDNA raw data?

Tags: ancestry.com

I just received my AncestryDNA raw data and I'm trying to find my Haplogroup X. I used the "ytree.morleydna.com" and I have that data. Can that data be used to determine X?
There are specific areas of Central Asia associated with Haplogroup X and I would like to narrow down as much as possible.

Comment: "Haplogroup" is associated with two things in consumer DNA jargon: mitochondrial DNA and the Y chromosome. To the best of my knowledge, the Ancestry DNA test does not provide either of these; they definitely do not provide any information about mitochondrial DNA. Is that what you mean by "haplogroup X"?